What causes a Python executable, that includes parallelization, to initiate an infinite loop of calls?
I want to create an executable of my Python code that contains parallel processing. Here's a sample code:
# example.py
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def producer():
    for i in range(6):
        print('Produced %s' % i)
        yield i

def main():
    out = Parallel(n_jobs=2, verbose=100, pre_dispatch='1.5*n_jobs')(
        delayed(sqrt)(i) for i in producer())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I create an .exe file using:
pyinstaller --onefile example.py

Now, when I execute the .exe file, it recursively calls itself repeatedly, resulting in an endless process. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?
Additional information: I am able to create functioning executables for Python codes that do not contain parallel execution.

The issue is caused by recursive invocation caused by joblib.Parallel which is recursively calling itself. To fix this issue add multiprocessing.freeze_support() above your main function call. Your code should look something like this
import multiprocessing
<previous code is the same>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()

An important note is that freeze_support() only works on windows.

Nevertheless, I tried this and it didn't work.
